# Apache: Proxy based on URL suffixes

Tags: apache-2.2, proxy, tomcat, redirect

My team has written an internal BI server, which generates HTML reports at links such as `/users/daily` or `/updates/questions`.

The server is written in [Grails](https://grails.org/), and it works perfectly with a classic Apache-Tomcat setting:

```
ProxyPass         /     http://localhost:8080/ nocanon
ProxyPassReverse  /     http://localhost:8080/
```

[image]

So

```
https://example.com/users/daily
```

Is proxied internally to

```
http://localhost:8080/users/daily
```

And served from the Tomcat servlet.

The server is successful, and I would like to deploy it thrice, to 3 different systems, distinguished by a URL suffix (`/dev`, `/stg`, `/prod`):

[image]

Meaning that `https://example.com/dev/users/daily` will be proxied from `http://localhost:8080/users/daily`, and `https://example.com/prod/users/daily` will be served from `http://localhost:8082/users/daily`.

I have tried some Apache `RewriteRule`s and `ProxyPass` rules, but could not find a working combination.

**How can I do the suffix-based internal routing in Apache that with working internal links?**

Answer (score 6):

You can do this with

```
<Location /dev>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule  ^/dev/(.*)  /$1
  ProxyPass         /  http://localhost:8080/ nocanon
  ProxyPassReverse  /  http://localhost:8080/
</Location>
```

and so on.  That will give you different proxies for the different URLs, and remove the leading /dev, /staging, or /prod from the URLs.

But there's a problem: links in the HTML coming back from Tomcat will have a URL base of /, not /dev etc.  To add the prefix back into the HTML, you'll have to use [mod_proxy_html](http://apache.webthing.com/mod_proxy_html/) or an equivalent to parse the HTML, modify it, and put it back together.  That can work, but there's a performance cost; ill-formed HTML can get mangled; you'll have to rewrite URLs in CSS and Javascript too; and the Javascript may be impossible to get right.

Another option that may be easier:  create new hostnames in DNS: dev.biserver.example.com, staging.biserver.example.com, and prod.biserver.example.com.  Then the URL rewriting would go away and you could do everything with virtual hosts, for example:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName dev.biserver.example.com
  ProxyPass         /  http://localhost:8080/ nocanon
  ProxyPassReverse  /  http://localhost:8080/
</VirtualHost>
```

and so on.

Comment: Actually, I have implemented the subdomains solutions as a temporary workaround. I'll take a look at the `mod_proxy_html` docs. I think that this blog post might be helpful: http://brian.olore.net/wp/tag/mod_proxy_html/