# multiple URL based reverse proxy

Tags: apache-2.4, reverse-proxy

After quite some time searching the Internet, I'm still struggling to configure my Apache Proxy virtual-host.

My setup is quite simple:

- server hosts several NodeJS-express apps

  - one hand-made REST API (listening on port 8080)
  - one [adminMongo](https://adminmongo.markmoffat.com/) (listening on port 8081)
- Apache listens on port 80 and is accessible at 10.8.0.1

Here's the Apache config file that's been close to working:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    <Location /custom>
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteRule ^/custom/(.*) /$1
        ProxyPass http://localhost:8080/
        ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:8080/
    </Location>

    <Location /mongo>
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteRule ^/mongo/(.*) /$1
        ProxyPass http://localhost:8081/
        ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:8081/
    </Location>
</Virtualhost>
```

This Vhost was inspired by this post: [Apache: proxy based on URL suffixes](https://serverfault.com/a/619489).

The main problem is that when I try to GET `http://10.8.0.01/mongo/` I'm redirected to `http://10.8.0.1/app/login/` (the express-app is doing this) which gives me a 404 error since my Apache has nothing to serve at `/`.

How can I match all of the URL beginning with `/mongo/` to serve my app listening on `http://127.0.0.1:8081/` ?

Any suggestion appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> The main problem is that when I try to GET http://10.8.0.01/mongo/ I'm redirected to http://10.8.0.1/app/login/ (the express-app is doing this) which gives me a 404 error since my Apache has nothing to serve at /.

This expected because of how you've configured it. This is even mentioned in the post you referenced:

> But there's a problem: links in the HTML coming back from Tomcat will have a URL base of /, not /dev etc. To add the prefix back into the HTML, you'll have to use mod_proxy_html or an equivalent to parse the HTML, modify it, and put it back together. That can work, but there's a performance cost; ill-formed HTML can get mangled; you'll have to rewrite URLs in CSS and Javascript too; and the Javascript may be impossible to get right.

So when you make a request to /mongo, it's being sent to the application as `/`, which means all returns are coming back as `/`, so the redirect is going to start with `/` instead of `/mongo/...`

As stated in the linked post, check the docs, or use subdomains.

Depending on your actual use case, you may be able to use the following:

```
<LocationMatch ^/custom>
  ProxyPass http://localhost:8080/
  ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:8080/
</LocationMatch>

<LocationMatch ^/mongo>
  ProxyPass http://localhost:8081/
  ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:8081/
</LocationMatch>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. However this doesn't seem to have any effect. Now I get a 404 error when trying to `GET /mongo`

Comment: It turns out that a simple nginx config works just fine :/ `location /mongo/ { proxy_pass http://localhost:8081/mongo/; }` . Why does it have to be so complicated with Apache ?

Comment: Adding the `ProxyHTMLEnabled` directive doesn't really help either.

Comment: That’s not a fair assessment. Your Nginx config is sending the proxied request to `localhost:8081/mongo`. Add the `/mongo` to your Apache config and I’m sure it would work just the same. A 404 means Apache is routing traffic to the proxied app, but your app doesn’t seem to support a `/` path, and needs `/mongo` instead

Comment: You're right. Sorry, I might've copied/pasted my config a little too fast. Actually, in the previously mentioned case, I configured my app to use a `/mongo` context so that all the links in the HTML would match the proxied URLs. However doing the equivalent with Apache still gives me a 404 error.

Comment: At that point you need to confirm what URL is expected for app and see what the app’s logs show. Or just use Nginx if you already have it running.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It's a bummer. I kinda have to use Apache. So I'm just going to have a look at the app's logs and see if they're consistent regarding the requested URLs. So just to be sure, I don't need any fancy `RewriteRule` directive or anything, right ? Just `ProxyPass http://localhost:8081/mongo/` and the `ProxyReverse` ?

Comment: From what I have seen, yes. You might have to play with the url value in the proxypass, but your app logs should know more If needed.